# How would I make this a UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, create-function

Problem: How to make a UDF from the following working code.

```
declare @currentweek as date
declare @1stweek as date
declare @2ndweek as date
declare @3rdweek as date
declare @4thweek as date
declare @5thweek as date

set @currentweek= dateadd(dd,0,(dateadd(DD,1-datepart(DW,GETDATE()),getdate())))
set @1stweek= dateadd(dd,7,(dateadd(DD,1-datepart(DW,GETDATE()),getdate())))
set @2ndweek= dateadd(dd,14,(dateadd(DD,1-datepart(DW,GETDATE()),getdate())))
set @3rdweek= dateadd(dd,21,(dateadd(DD,1-datepart(DW,GETDATE()),getdate())))
set @4thweek= dateadd(dd,28,(dateadd(DD,1-datepart(DW,GETDATE()),getdate())))
set @5thweek= dateadd(dd,35,(dateadd(DD,1-datepart(DW,GETDATE()),getdate())))

select


case 
    when ([1] >= @currentweek and [1]<@1stweek)and ([2] >= @currentweek and [2]<@1stweek) and ([3] >= @currentweek and [3]<@1stweek)then 'RAP'
    when ([2] >= @currentweek and [2]<@1stweek)and ([3] >= @currentweek and [3]<@1stweek) then 'RA'
    when ([1] >= @currentweek and [1]<@1stweek)and ([3] >= @currentweek and [3]<@1stweek) then 'AP'
    when [3] >= @currentweek and [3]<@1stweek then 'A'
    when ([1] >= @currentweek and [1]<@1stweek)and ([2] >= @currentweek and [2]<@1stweek) then 'RP'
    when [2] >= @currentweek and [2]<@1stweek then 'R' 
    when [1] >= @currentweek and [1]<@1stweek then 'P' 

    else null 
end as [current week]
,case 
    when ([1] >= @1stweek and [1]<@2ndweek)and ([2] >= @1stweek and [2]<@2ndweek) and ([3] >= @1stweek and [3]<@2ndweek)then 'RAP'
    when ([2] >= @1stweek and [2]<@2ndweek)and ([3] >= @1stweek and [3]<@2ndweek) then 'RA'
    when ([1] >= @1stweek and [1]<@2ndweek)and ([3] >= @1stweek and [3]<@2ndweek) then 'AP'
    when [3] >= @1stweek and [3]<@2ndweek then 'A'
    when (([1] >= @1stweek and [1]<@2ndweek)and ([2] >= @1stweek and [2]<@2ndweek)) then 'RP'
    when [2] >=@1stweek and [2] < @2ndweek then 'R'
    when [1] >=@1stweek and [1] < @2ndweek then 'P'
    else null
end as [Next week Week]
```

I have tried to research the `CREATE Function` command:

I came up with

```
CREATE FUNCTION testudf()
returns table
as
begin

    Inserted the code

End
Go
```

However that did not work. Any ideas?

EDIT: Added the word table next to returns.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure RollingDateRAP, Line 81
>   Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.

Comment: *Did not work* - how?? Did you get an error? If so, please post the complete and precise error message! If not - in what way did it not work?

Comment: Looks like you're just missing the word "TABLE" after "returns"

Comment: Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure RollingDateRAP, Line 20
Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.
Msg 455, Level 16, State 2, Procedure RollingDateRAP, Line 20
The last statement included within a function must be a return statement.

Comment: @tab: looks like that reduced the error to just one Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure testudf, Line 81
Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.

Comment: Are [1], [2], etc.. place holders? If they are suppose to represent numbers, you look to be comparing a numeric value to a date.

Comment: Ahz They are column names from a seperate table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION testudf()
returns @tblOut  TABLE (
[current week] varchar(31)
,[Next week Week] varchar(31)
)
as
begin



   declare @currentweek as date
declare @1stweek as date
declare @2ndweek as date
declare @3rdweek as date
declare @4thweek as date
declare @5thweek as date

set @currentweek= dateadd(dd,0,(dateadd(DD,1-datepart(DW,GETDATE()),getdate())))
set @1stweek= dateadd(dd,7,(dateadd(DD,1-datepart(DW,GETDATE()),getdate())))
set @2ndweek= dateadd(dd,14,(dateadd(DD,1-datepart(DW,GETDATE()),getdate())))
set @3rdweek= dateadd(dd,21,(dateadd(DD,1-datepart(DW,GETDATE()),getdate())))
set @4thweek= dateadd(dd,28,(dateadd(DD,1-datepart(DW,GETDATE()),getdate())))
set @5thweek= dateadd(dd,35,(dateadd(DD,1-datepart(DW,GETDATE()),getdate())))

INSERT INTO @tblOut
select


case 
    when ([1] >= @currentweek and [1]<@1stweek)and ([2] >= @currentweek and [2]<@1stweek) and ([3] >= @currentweek and [3]<@1stweek)then 'RAP'
    when ([2] >= @currentweek and [2]<@1stweek)and ([3] >= @currentweek and [3]<@1stweek) then 'RA'
    when ([1] >= @currentweek and [1]<@1stweek)and ([3] >= @currentweek and [3]<@1stweek) then 'AP'
    when [3] >= @currentweek and [3]<@1stweek then 'A'
    when ([1] >= @currentweek and [1]<@1stweek)and ([2] >= @currentweek and [2]<@1stweek) then 'RP'
    when [2] >= @currentweek and [2]<@1stweek then 'R' 
    when [1] >= @currentweek and [1]<@1stweek then 'P' 

    else null 
end as [current week]
,case 
    when ([1] >= @1stweek and [1]<@2ndweek)and ([2] >= @1stweek and [2]<@2ndweek) and ([3] >= @1stweek and [3]<@2ndweek)then 'RAP'
    when ([2] >= @1stweek and [2]<@2ndweek)and ([3] >= @1stweek and [3]<@2ndweek) then 'RA'
    when ([1] >= @1stweek and [1]<@2ndweek)and ([3] >= @1stweek and [3]<@2ndweek) then 'AP'
    when [3] >= @1stweek and [3]<@2ndweek then 'A'
    when (([1] >= @1stweek and [1]<@2ndweek)and ([2] >= @1stweek and [2]<@2ndweek)) then 'RP'
    when [2] >=@1stweek and [2] < @2ndweek then 'R'
    when [1] >=@1stweek and [1] < @2ndweek then 'P'
    else null
end as [Next week Week];

RETURN;

End
Go
```